# How can I enable clipboard in Ubuntu Vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim, clipboard

[image]
I am Using Ubuntu and vim.

I want to write stack over flow's question in Vim and paste here in browser, so I looked this and enabled clipboard.

https://superuser.com/questions/432708/copying-to-system-clipboard-with-vim-not-working-under-ubuntu

and installed gvim.

However, this poping up, but I cannot paste into the browser.

[image]

what should I do?

I found the help, thankyou
[image]

Comment: You need to use the CLIPBOARD `"+` register - `"+y` in your case. type `:help "+` for a explanation

Comment: Thank you Sorin,  I am going to integrate unamad and unamede plus .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the X11-based systems (ie. Linux and most other UNIX-like systems) you can copy-on-select, and can be pasted with the middle mouse button (In the vim and others).

Also, you can use this link for more information.

https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim